# Assign object based on user selection of database row

Tags: javascript, eval

Sorry for a somewhat misleading title - I can't think of a way to easily name this.

I have an HTML/JS single-page application (based on custom framework, but it doesn't matter).  When the app starts, it makes an ajax call to the server to retrieve data.  The returned data is an array of objects representing scenarios that can then be "run" but the application.  It looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Scenario 1',
    ... (lots of other stuff)
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Scenario 2',
    ... (lots of other stuff)
  },
  ...
]
```

The app then presents a list of scenarios to the user to choose which one to run - the list displays the names - and the user can simply click on one of them to run the corresponding scenario.

The javascript part of the application is two-fold.  There's the generic part and specific scenario parts.  To continue the simplified example above, I'll have:

```
application.js
scenarioOne.js
scenarioTwo.js
```

`scenarioX.js` files contain object definitions with a common prototype, for example:

```
var scenarioOne = {
    var1: 'abc',
    ...
    init: function() { ... },
    start: function() { ... },
    reset: function() { ... },
    processSpecial: function() { ... },
    ...
}
```

This way, once I have a reference to a specific scenario object, I can call methods on it without worrying about which scenario I am dealing with.

So far so good - and this whole thing works fine.  What I am struggling with is how to pick the correct scenario based on user selection.  In my main `appliation.js`, I want to have something like this (pseudo-code):

```
var scenario;

switch(selected scenario) {
case 'scenario1':
    scenario = scenarioOne;
    break;
case 'scenario2':
    sceario = scenarioTwo;
    break;
...
}

scenario.init();
scenario.start();
```

For obvious reasons, I cannot rely on selected scenario IDs, as these are dictated by the server and can change.  I feel that the javascript object to use should be specified by the server as part of the scenario data (I do have control over the server, so it's not a problem), so the data returned from server would become:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Scenario 1',
    jsobject: 'scenarioOne',
    ... (lots of other stuff)
  },
  ...
]
```

However then I would have to use `eval` to get the right object:

```
eval('scenario = ' + serverdata[selected_id].jsobject);
```

And I'm less than a big fan of `eval`.

So, is there a better way of dealing with this?  Or is `eval` my friend here?

Comment: Do you mean you would end up with something like this: `eval('var scenario = ' + (serverdata[selected_id].jsobject + ';')`? And that you want a non-eval option to consider?

Comment: What's wrong with `eval()`? It's more backward compatible. When writing my own `post()` function I use `eval()` to evaluate `json_encode()`ed responses from PHP .

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes, that's right - I updated my question.  And, yes, I wonder if there's a non-eval option available.

Comment: `scenario = JSON.Parse(serverdata[selected_id].jsobject);`  obviously with code to catch an error in case of invalid json.

Comment: @Rooster I don't see how this would work.  `serverdata[selected_id].jsobject` is a string, e.g. `"scenarioOne"` - calling `JSON.parse` on it would result in an error.

Comment: @PHPglue At present, I don't get the js file name from the server - but I can alter the server response in any way I need.

Comment: @AleksG sorry I misunderstood your problem.  are you doing all of this in global scope?

Comment: I don't think you should be afraid of `eval()` for this; it's pitfalls are really overblown and meant to warn inexperienced developers to be careful. In this situation, since you're running code you control and not arbitrary code (like something someone submits, given to another user), I don't think you have a compelling reason not to use `eval()` here. (Here's a really awkward way to do it with [`new Function()`](http://jsfiddle.net/qukakmo6/)) A simpler alternative could be to store your scenarios in a `scenarios` object, so you can simply `var scenario = scenarios[selectedScenario]`.

Comment: @PHPglue no I was thinking of JSON.parse as JSON.stringify would do the opposite of what would be needed...but I did capitalize the p incorrectly and initially misunderstand the problem ;P

Comment: Yeah, if trying to parse a string from the Server, it's `JSON.parse()` or `eval()`. Why no mention of AJAX? Are you not performing an XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: More code needed. Client and Server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this all in global scope, then all the variables will live on the window object.

so you could do:

```
scenario = window[serverdata[selected_id].jsobject];
```

[heres a fiddle demonstrating this all simple like](http://jsfiddle.net/boye6LLy/)

Comment: This is not the solution to the problem.

Comment: @PHPglue It took me a bit to understand but I think @Rooster's solution is valid but could certainly use some elaboration:

The scenario files would all have to be on the client side **or** the scenario js file would have to be fetched from the server and added to the DOM.  With the format of `var scenarioName = function { ... };` as long as `scenarioName` was documented, the variable would be accessible as a string index on the window object (the global scope Rooster was talking about).  `window["scenarioName"] should get the function.

Comment: @PHPglue how is it not?

Comment: No, it makes no sense. It assumes that somehow there  is JSON already made on the Client side. This is just Object property access.

Comment: @PHPglue He said in his question, "scenarioX.js files contain object definitions with a common prototype, for example: var scenarioOne = {...." therefore, window['scenarioOne'] == scenarioOne (assuming scenarioOne was loaded globally, which it must be)

Comment: @PHPglue Ahh I see what you're saying.  However, Aleks G already has some information locally.  All he would need to do is add additional information to the initially rendered page which contained the path to the scenario's js file.  Such as `data-src="path/to/js"`.

Comment: @Rooster I think you and I were assuming the JSON he showed in his question was part of some data on the client side, but I'm not sure it is.  However, *some* information is on the client side for rendering so Aleks could just add a data attr to each row with the path to the js and your answer is still valid I think.

Comment: @PHPglue - I think you're misunderstanding the intent of the question. The OP wants to set a variable to another variable using a string for the variable name stored in another variable (object/array). JSON is really beside the point.

Comment: @EricH You and I are on the same page.  I'm going to hold off on any more comments until the OP chimes in.

Comment: @PHPglue - Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qukakmo6/2/ `window[selected_scenario_string]` would work simply because it's the same as `var selected_scenario` declared in the global scope.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying. That's what OP already showed us. You would still need to `eval()` the entire Object coming back from the Sever.

Comment: @PHPglue You wouldn't if you appended a script tag to your DOM (as it gets evaluated at that time) with an src attr set to the path of the scenario js file on the server as far as I know.

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect this much discussion!  Rooster is correct  and @JaredFarrish got the point correctly, too.  This solution does what I need.

Comment: For the benefit of all involved, injecting a `<script src="/path/to/scenarioX.js">` is not going to work, because each scenario may be run more than once.  Therefore all scenario js files are included from the beginning.  Each one defines a corresponding object - and at run time I need to assign one of these objects to a known variable, based on user selection.